# Is a 'hackproductivity' tag appropriate for MS Office questions relating to the ongoing hackathon?

Tags: discussion, tags

I posted a question on a site where Microsoft is running a hackathon, and [it was suggested](https://hackproductivity.devpost.com/forum_topics/6353-yeoman-default-add-in-instructions) that I tag [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063377/word-add-in-get-full-document-text) with [hackproductivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hackproductivity).

This tag didn't exist on the site already, so I wasn't sure if I should create it. I was surprised it didn't already exist, since a user with lower reputation wouldn't have been able to create it.

The tag has now been edited out of my question by another user.

Is this a good tag? Should I have created it?

Comment: Tags for ephemeral events hasn't been very useful.

Comment: @braiam I assumed MS had some sort of deal with SO as I've seen stuff like that in the past.

Comment: No. It hasn't. Tags are means to make "answerers" to find questions thy are able to "answer". When you create a new tag but you aren't the one that will going to answer them, it results in a less than ideal situation if someone uses that tag as their only tag.

Comment: @Braiam well from what you say it sounds like what I did was ok and now my tag has been removed. Rolled it back

Comment: [tag:office-js] is a good tag, capturing the specific topic of your question and letting the folks at MS who deal with it - *and anyone else interested* - find it if they wish to. Stick with that.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride No, it's *not* okay.  That tag has no business being a tag on the site at all.

Comment: @servy ok. good to know. Maybe Microsoft should stop advertising this because I'm not going to be the only one who does this. As they tell anyone who needs help to do it and the hackathon still has about 60 days left.

Comment: It'd be great if you replied to that Microsoft person to point them to this question, so that such mistakes can be avoided in the future :)

Comment: @Stijn I have done that and I hope they will change the marketing materials https://hackproductivity.devpost.com/forum_topics/6356-microsft-your-tag-doesn-t-exists-on-stackoverflow?page=1

Comment: It sounds like this person is confusing Stack Overflow with Twitter...

Comment: Microsoft employees, if you're reading this: *tag* is not the same as *hashtag*.

Comment: That's a moderator of that forum, but I don't see anything in their profile that indicates that they're a MS employee (they could be, but I'm certainly not seeing it)

Comment: @Servy you're right I thought they mentioned the tag on their front-page too, but I guess not, it was just a one time mistake, by a non-developer, non-MS employee from DevPost. The front page says to use 'ms-office' which I've updated my question to use.

Comment: @servy [Looks like](https://www.linkedin.com/in/stefanie-maccarone-57b71610) she is actually an employee of the forum

Comment: @servy this will be good for her to see non-the-less as she likely encourages use of StackoverFlow for multiple companies using DevPost for hackathons.

Comment: She also doesn't appear to be a user here at Stack Overflow, so unless someone adds a link to this thread, I don't think she's going to see this. Not a whole lot of Stefanie's on SO, though she could be using a pseudonym.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Sure, I'm not saying someone shouldn't tell her she's giving bad advice, but there's somewhat of a difference between a MS employee and an employee/moderator on a forum that is discussing MS related topics.

Comment: @BSMP she already has said she saw this thread here (latest post) https://hackproductivity.devpost.com/forum_topics/6356-microsft-your-tag-doesn-t-exists-on-stackoverflow?page=1

Comment: Suggesting to post to "Microsoft StackOverflow forums", what could go wrong? Maybe we should suggest that clueless newbies post on *their* forum instead. \*diabolical laughter\*

Comment: `Microsoft StackOverflow forum`; three things wrong there (it's not 'Microsoft Stack Overflow', it's 'Stack Overflow', and we aren't a forum). Also `their support team will help you`- no, just no, Microsoft... I've seen MS support reps take this stance with Stack Overflow before, perhaps it's time the SE team send them a letter to let them know what Stack Overflow is actually for?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging):

> #### What are tags, and how should I use them?
>
> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.

HackProductivity is not the topic of the question at all (or any other question on Stack Overflow). To put it in other words, the answer to the question would be the same if you encountered the problem during your normal work instead of a hackathon. Therefore, the tag shouldn't have been created, but it will be deleted *automatically* if it has no associated questions.

Answer (score 14):

That's not what tags are for.  That would be a meta tag, and meta tags aren't appropriate on the site.

The tag has already been removed, and will likely end up being deleted at the end of the day.  You should not be adding the tag back onto your question.

If you want to share the question with other people, and indicate that it's associated with a particular event, then feel free to use the "share" option on the question to share it on various social media platforms, most of which (I would presume) are going to have some way of allowing you to indicate that your question is related to this particular event.

Comment: ok sorry I made the tag can someone delete it?

Comment: It will be *automatically* deleted once the (daily) script sees it doesn't have any questions associated with it.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride From the post, "The tag has already been removed, and will likely end up being deleted at the end of the day."